# Protobuf parser parses other objects?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-java

I have been using protocol buffers for a project of mine in Java. I have found that a parser for a protobuf object, parses other Protobuf data and does not throw an exception. Instead it returns a object of the parser type without any data (not the default instance)

Below is my test proto file

```
option java_package = "tester";
option java_outer_classname = "TestProto";

message A{
    string message = 1;
}

message B{
    int64 id = 1;
}
```

below is my test code

```
 TestProto.A a = TestProto.A.newBuilder().setMessage("My Test Message").build();
 TestProto.B b = TestProto.B.getDefaultInstance().getParserForType().parseFrom(a.toByteString());

 System.out.println("Is default instnace :" + (b.getDefaultInstanceForType() == b));
```

this code works without an exception and the result is 'false'.

I cannot understand this behaviour,I am in need of a situation where I have to parse some serialized protobuf objects and If one parser fails I have to try the other parser. How can I solve this.

thanks.

Comment: Check the contents of `getUnknownFields` (or `getUnknownFieldSet`, or similar. I forget the exact method name).

Comment: But also, in general, `b.getDefaultInstanceForType() == b` is wrong: use `equals` to compare the instances.

Comment: You will generally have a hard time on this, because fields are `optional` by default in proto3. Which means if two messages have totally different fields (and field IDs), the are still assignable fine to each other. Only the content would go lost, since the parser assumes it's just an optional field it doesn't know about.

Comment: However in this specific example there should be an error, since the same field ID (1) is used for 2 different types.

Comment: @Matthias247 it could be parsing via the "packed" logic, which would match length-prefix; it would take quite a fluke to not cause a varint violation, but it is theoretically possible; I would have thought it wouldn't do that unless it was "repeated", but... meh

Comment: @Andy that isn't an unknown field.

Comment: @Matthias247 follow up thought that validates "packed" as the cause: pure ASCII will *always* be valid varint. I expect the object has id=101

Comment: @AndyTurner I was checking whether the parser returned same singleton object (default instance) by checking the reference , thats why I used "=="

Comment: @AndyTurner I used "equals" also, and it too returns false in this case

Comment: @AndyTurner using getUnknownFields can solve the issue here, but IMO checking for whether there is any unknown field and ignoring the message if it does, will result in not being able to update the message structure in the future. Therefore I will accept Marc Gravells answer and look into a more of a design change of the application

Comment: Thanks for quick responses :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protobuf is predicated on both ends knowing in advance - and agreeing on - the data structure. If you attempt to interpret a message with a **radically different** structure, precisely zero guarantees are made.

- it could throw an error
- it could work and present you with well-intentioned gibberish
- it could work and preserve everything required as unknown fields

All are possible.

Basically: you can't rely on this behaviour.

Note: there *are* guarantees made regarding *certain* changes such as adding or removing fields (ensuring that they aren't reused later with different types/meanings). That is fine and expected. But other changes are simply not defined.

---

> I am in need of a situation where I have to parse some serialized protobuf objects and If one parser fails I have to try the other parser. How can I solve this.

You cannot.

Comment: Note to self: I'm 99.5% sure that protobuf-net would actually throw an exception in this case. Since this is an undefined scenario neither behaviour is more correct or more wrong, but now I'm wondering whether I should at least make it behave the same. But in reality: if you hit this problem, you've already messed up your data pretty badly, so... maybe it is better to just leave it alone. It certainly doesn't seem to be worth spending much time on. There might be a case for "I changed my packed repeated field (which  ever had one value in it) to an optional field, and now it fails", though

Comment: "You cannot." Might not be always true. In cases when you are able to modify schema of incoming data you can design it with using [`oneof`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#oneof) keyword or [`Any`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any) type and some kind of description of what type an `Any` filed actually holds.

Comment: @plastique changing to `Any` is a layout-breaking change; `oneof` doesn't apply in the case shown in the question; so yes, there *can be* ways to handle this *in specific cases*, but: not the one shown